# Как внутри фрагмента получить title таба?

Tags: android

Простите, если вопрос задан слишком сложно, сейчас попробую объяснить.
Мне нужно сделать tabLayout + viewPager (это готово).
Есть activity и адаптер, наследованный от FragmentStatePagerAdapter. 
Я использую только один класс для 32 табов, т.к. вьюхи у всех них одинаковые.
Но для каждого фрагмента надо использовать разный реквест для получения данных. И мне надо взять название конкретного таба (они все разные) и сделать реквест. Как получить название таба? Спасибо

**EDIT**
pavlofff подкинул идею с позицией и я зацепился за ней. Внутри фрагмента обратился к tabLayout Activity, брал позицию и вытаскивал со списка названий, который передал в фрагмент. Всем большое спасибо:)

Comment: наверное лучше привязаться к позиции, а не к названию или названия в одной и той же позиции может менятся?

Comment: может я не так понял, но у вас 32 таба... а не многовато ли? может сделать фрагмент со обычным списком, который будет содержать названия, которые в табах, при на нажатии на элемент списка выводить фрагмент с вьюхой, которая одинакова для таб. Брать название и передавать его во фрагмент будет очень просто, ну и в этом фрагменте делать реквест.

Comment: Я бы так и сделал, но в тз чётко описано, что нужны табы. 
pavloff, название не меняется. Просто нужно его получить.

Comment: можешь попробовать прописать интерфейс который будет обновлять фрагмент во в ViewPager, каждый раз когда перелистываешь фрагменты. В интерфейсе определить метод который будет принимать текущее значение Tab и реализовать этот интерфейс в фрагменте. Подробнее тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088076/update-fragment-from-viewpager